# Set Notation with Intercepts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I really love set notation, and I'm finding myself using it more and more. My question is whether this would be a valid symbolic representation of intercepts.

For example, take $$y=x^2-10x+16$$

The $x$-intercepts are obviously at $x=8$ and $x=2$. Now, set-builder notation would say $\{x|x=8,2\}$ to imply that $x$ belongs to the set of real numbers. However, couldn't we say that $x\in\{2,8\}$, because $x$ is an element in the set of 2 or 8. The real numbers is implied by the fact that 2 and 8 are real, and $x$ must be a member of the set to be a zero.

Comment: You are right that the set $\{x:x=8 \mbox{ or }x=2\}$, can be written as $\{2,8\}.$ Where you want to be careful is that the points $2,8$ are not x-intercepts (you do not actually say this but you *seem* to come close). An x-intercept is a point, $(x_0,0)$ that is on your graph. So the x-intercepts are the points $(2,0)$, and $(8,0)$, but the zeros are in fact you set.

Comment: I agree...your notation really doesn't show that there is an equality here, just that the solutions are part of a set which you define $\{2,8\}$.  Since they are intercepts, it would be much better to include the fact that you are in the set $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that, I meant zeros. So this would be an acceptable way to represent the zeros?  I'm so glad.

Comment: It would be acceptable to say that the set of zeros of $y=x^2+10x+16$ is the set $\{2,8\}$.

Comment: For $x=2$, $x^2+10x+16=4+20+16=40$ which isn't a zero.  ${-2,-8}$ are the zeros.  The factors are $(x+8)(x+2)$, yes though the actual x values for a zero are the negatives of that.

Comment: Either you mean the intercepts are $-2$ and $-8$ or $y=x^2-10x+16$.  Besides that, $\{x\in\mathbb R|x^2+10x+16=0\}=\{-2,-8\}$.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant $y=x^2-10x+16$. I will correct it in the original question.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, I know that there are real roots here, but aren't the roots of a quadratic always in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue I don’t quite understand your point of view, but as the real numbers are naturally embedded in the set of complex number we may claim that each real number “is” a complex number.